# Set Activity/Presence Command for Discord.js-Commando

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I have this command that sets the bot's "Playing" status:

```js
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const { RichEmbed } = require('discord.js');
class sets extends commando.Command {
  constructor(client) {
      super(client, {
          name: 'setgame',
          group: 'owner',
          memberName: 'setgame',
          description: 'Sets the Bots\' activity',
          examples: ['Playing __on many servers!__'],
          args: [
            {
            key: "game",
            prompt: "What do you want to set my game as?",
            type: "string"
           }
          ]
      });
  }
  async run(message, { game } ) {
    if (message.author.id !== "442918106378010635"){
      message.channel.send("That's for TheRSC only!");
    }
    
    else {

      this.client.bot.setActivity(game)
      const embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0x00AE86)
        .setDescription("Game set!");
      message.channel.send({embed});;
    }
  }  
}

module.exports = sets;;
```

I ran into a few bugs before and managed to fix them, but this one stumps me. No matter how I code it, I keep getting: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setActivity' of undefined`
I've tried a few things, having *text* be defined in run, putting args.game into .setActivity() and it keeps spitting out that error. I tried the splitting the args method but that didn't work either. Any ideas? (As a side note, I'd also like to turn this into a .setPresence command if possible.)

*Note: I am a beginner at coding, so I may be doing something that the average coder wouldn't.*

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
client.bot.setActivity(game)
```

to

```
client.user.setActivity(game)
```

You can take a look at this example provided by [the official documentation on setActivity()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity) if you need more help, or if my solution doesn't work.

```
client.user.setActivity('YouTube', { type: 'WATCHING' })
  .then(presence => console.log(`Activity set to ${presence.game ? presence.game.name : 'none'}`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

EDIT: I still think it has something to do with the `.bot` part because the only [reference on the documentation of `.bot`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=bot) was a boolean of whether or not a user was a bot.

Comment: If I do that, I get `TypeError: this.client.user.setActivity is not a function`
Also, what I'm trying to do is code a command to change the Playing line to something else.

Comment: I've already looked at the documentation, but it only shows how to set it directly, not through args (that, or I'm just too new at this to understand how to put things together).

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.this` from before client.bot.setActivity? Also, do you define what type of status you are setting (ie, playing, watching, streaming,)?

Comment: I had to add `this.` otherwise it spits out `ReferenceError: client is not defined`
And setting the status type has no effect either. `this.client.bot.setActivity(game, { type: 'PLAYING'})`